# How to hide linear background on images?

Tags: html, image, css, background

I'm looking for the linear background to not cover the image; I already tried using a div with white background, or using no background tag, but obviously doesn't work.

```css
#heading:before {
    background: linear-gradient(#111111 0%, #123467 65%);
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading" >
  <img style="position:absolute;left:5%" src="images/gray_circle_logo.png" width="10%"/>
</div>
```

Really thanks
Andrew

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Surely you know when the heading is an image?  Couldn't you just add a class that removes the before for those type headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `z-index: 1` is positioning the `:after` pseudo element infront of the image.

Either remove the `z-index` or give the image a higher `z-index`.

**Removed z-index**

```css
#heading:before {
    background: linear-gradient(#111111 0%, #123467 65%);
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="heading" >
  <img style="position:absolute;left:5%" src="images/gray_circle_logo.png" width="10%"/>
</div>
```

**Image with z-index**

```css
#heading:before {
    background: linear-gradient(#111111 0%, #123467 65%);
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#heading img {
  /* absolute positioning from inline styles */
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading" >
  <img style="position:absolute;left:5%" src="images/gray_circle_logo.png" width="10%"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Too fast! Really thanks, I'm still learning but sometimes we need people!

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index: -1;` on the pseudo-element to move it behind the image:

```css
#heading:before {
    background: linear-gradient(#111111 0%, #123467 65%);
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading" >
  <img style="position:absolute;left:5%" src="https://placehold.it/80x80/fa0" width="10%"/>
</div>
```